# svcutil.exe generating 2 partial classes

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, svcutil.exe

I am writing a .NET 4.0 app and have control over both the WCF service and client.
I am using svcutil to generate proxy classes for my services, combining several services.

```
svcutil /o:.\ServiceProxies\NavigatorServiceWCFProxy.cs /ct:System.Collections.Generic.List`1 /namespace:*,FIS.Navigator.Common.NavigatorService /noconfig http://localhost/NavigatorService/NavigatorService.svc?wsdl
```

It generated two class look like:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute(System.Runtime.Serialization, 4.0.0.0)]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name=RequestBase, Namespace=http://schemas.datacontract.org/Navigator/Base)]
public partial class RequestBase : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject
{

}
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute(svcutil, 4.0.30319.1)]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute(code)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace=http://schemas.datacontract.org/Navigator/Base)]
public partial class RequestBase
{
}
```

If we add a service reference only one partial class is generated in reference.cs Why it is creating two Classes?
how can i generate only one partial class same as reference.cs using svcutil ?

Comment: Why is this important? Two partial classes = 1 class. It's generated code, and will always be unpredictable.

Comment: it is genrating two partial classes with same properties so when i am trying to read any property the compiler throwing an error as "ambiguity between two classes "

Comment: is it possible to restrict to generate two partial classes using svcutill ?

Comment: Well there must be a way because visual studio uses it to generate code. What happens if you drop all other parameters when calling it? Just point at the wsdl.

Comment: Also, do you own the service code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above problem has been removed when i pass /importXmlTypes parameter to the svcutil.exe.

Answer (score 4):

For faultHandling use the option /useSerializerForFaults to avoid duplicates